# Cordova does not play local mp3 file on Windows Phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to play an mp3 file stored locally in a subfolder.

```
function audioHandlers() {
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        playAudio("media/intro.mp3");
    });
}



function playAudio(url) {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function () {
            alert("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function (err) {
            var error = document.getElementById("error");
            var msg: string = JSON.stringify(err);
            error.textContent = msg;
        }
        );
    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```

I get a `file not found`. How does the url need to look like for Windows Phone?

Comment: I want to ask the same question!  for Windows and iPhone!  the MP3 can only play in Android

Answer (score 0):

To access your local cordova files you have to prefix  your source path with `ms-appx:///` on `windows phone 8.1`. You should try something like:

```
function audioHandlers() {
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    var prefix = "ms-appx:///";
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        playAudio( prefix + "media/intro.mp3");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The path for local assets is different for android and windows phone 8.1. Try using window.local.href:

```
function audioHandlers() {
    var path = window.location.href;
    path = path.substr(path, path.length - 10);
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        playAudio(path + "media/intro.mp3";);
    });
}
```

This should generate a different path for each platform.